# How to restrict user to use login page when he / she is logged in

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a react app where I want to make my routes private, like when user is not logged they cannot see the other pages and vice-versa.

The first one is working fine when I am not logged in I am redirecting them to login page i.e "/" this route.

But when I am logged and I am going to this "/" url I am able to go to login

**"/" this is my login page**

My code

```
  export const  AuthRoute=({component:Component, ...rest}) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('JWT_Token') 
    console.log(token)
    return (
       <Route {...rest} render={
         (props => {
           if(token)
           {

             return <Component {...props}/>
           }
           else{
             return <Redirect to={{
               pathname:"/",
               state:{
                 from:props.location
               }
             }} />
           }
         })
       }/>
    )
}
```

My route file

```
    <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={ login } />          
    <AuthRoute  path="/welcome" component={ welcome } /> 
    <AuthRoute  path="/profile" component={ profile } />
    </Switch>
```

**I am checking user with my localstorage**

On logout I am deleting the token so if no token I will logout user.

What I am doing wrong don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a small wrapper over Route for login component to redirect to /welcome when loggedIn

```
export const LoginRoute=({component:Component, ...rest}) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('JWT_Token') 

    return (
       <Route {...rest} render={
         (props => {
           if(token)
           {

             return <Redirect to="/welcome"/>
           }
           else{
             return <Component {...props}/>
           }
         })
       }/>
    );
}

...
<LoginRoute exact path="/" component={ login } />
```

Comment: You are saying to create one more component for Login auth like I have done earlier for other routes ?

Comment: yes, that is ccorrect. Either that or you can simply implement this logic inside of Login component

Comment: So this is the correct approach ? as I am new to react that's why I am asking, as I have worked on Vue and there we got router,before something for these things